# Javascript sort() array of mixed data type

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

If I have an array like:

```
["23", "765", "sfasf", "2.3E-3", "2.3cE-3"]
```

How can I order it so numbers(decimals, floats or scientific notation) are ordered ascending and after those strings that aren't numbers(for example "sfasf" or "2.3cE-3")?

Expected order of the example array:

```
["2.3E-3", "23", "765", "2.3cE-3", "sfasf"]
```

The order of the strings that can't be converted to numbers doesn't matter, they just must be at the end.

Solution from answer:

```
 $scope.cleanAndOrder = function(dbo, fieldName) {
    var textareaId = "textarea"+"_"+fieldName ;
    var textarea= document.getElementById(textareaId);

    //(+b && (+a!=a)) : return true (converted to 1) if b is a number and a isn't
    //(a-b) : then compare the numbers if the first comparaison isn't enough
    textarea.value = dbo.attributes[fieldName].sort(function(a,b){ return (+b && !+a) || (a-b) }).join("\n");
    var lines = textarea.value.split("\n");
    textarea.setAttribute('rows', lines.length +2);
 }
```

Comment: Use lo-dash or underscore :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment could you point out a particular function, please?

Comment: Do you want a specific order for strings ?

Comment: No the string order was irrelevant in this case!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
var arr = arr.sort(function(a,b){ return ((+b==b) && (+a!=a)) || (a-b) })
```

The idea is to make two comparisons:

- `(+b==b) && (+a!=a)` : return `true` (converted to `1`) if `b` is a number and `a` isn't
- `a-b` : then compare the numbers if the first comparaison isn't enough

More in depth : `+a` converts `a` to a number. It is equal (for `==`, not `for ===`) to `a` when and only when `+a` is a number (remember, `NaN` isn't equal to `NaN`).

Comment: can u please add some explanation for the code u posted?

Comment: Awesome! works like a charm I will accept your answer in a few min. Thanks.

Comment: @DenysSéguret what a-b for?

Comment: @Alex It's just the difference. If you want to sort numbers you do `[3, 32, -4, 21].sort(function(a,b){ return a-b })`

Comment: @DenysSéguret Hey thanks again but it swops some values if I run the operation consecutively with the following values:                  0.00000000067
asdas
6.14475066
2323.324324
234E12
2.11220065
2.3EE-3
90.96dsfsdf936856
dsfsdf
--2.3E-3
38.2046219'

Comment: @AlExTsm I see no problem in `['0.00000000067', 'asdas', '6.14475066', '2323.324324', '234E12', '2.11220065', '2.3EE-3', '90.96dsfsdf936856', 'dsfsdf', '--2.3E-3', '38.2046219'].sort(function(a,b){ return ((+b==b) && (+a!=a)) || (a-b) })`. If necessary can you write a failing example in http://jsbin.com ?

Comment: You are right it has nothing to do with your solution. I am ordering and removing empty lines(which are not stored as values within the array). I think the issue is related with (\n) or white-spaces, still trying to reproduce again. I posted in my question the function I am running on blur of the textarea.

Comment: @DenysSéguret The problem comes when I copy existing values within the textarea and paste them agin. I will have to look into that probaply copying and pasting some "\n" I think

Comment: @AlExTsm Please make a fiddle and maybe come to the [JS room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript)

Comment: I have never used it(to create) I'll take a look after work. Looks so comfortable

Answer (score 0):

[`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function accept a function comparaison as parameter.

Define your

```
function compareFct(a, b) {
    if (isNaN(a)) {
        if (isNaN(b)) {  // a and b are strings
            return a.localeCompare(b);
        } else {         // a string and b number
            return 1;  // a > b
        }
    } else {
        if (isNaN(b)) {  // a number and b string
            return -1;  // a < b
        } else {         // a and b are numbers
            return parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b);
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
yourArray.sort(compareFct);
```